# Why is Apache doing something odd with files containing .map. in the name?

Tags: apache-2.2

When I tried to use a javascript file with a name blah.map.foo.js it kept failing with a syntax error. After much effort tracking down why, it turns out that when I open an empty file called blah.map.foo.html I get this output to my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Menu for /blah.map.foo.html</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Menu for /blah.map.foo.html</h1>
<hr />



</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I change the .map. in the filename to something else, I just get a blank page as I would expect. I did a quick search through our apache config files for ".map" but didn't find anything that might cause the behaviour.

Is this some kind of standard functionality? (Googling "menu for" gets a whole lot of restaurants...)

If not standard, where should I look to find out what's going on?

Background: I work in a corporate environment with a head office that sets up much of the Apache configuration, though I can add my own customisations and have full access to the config files. Thanks to staff movements, this behaviour may have been previously built by someone and no longer known about by current staff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only Apache directive I'm aware of that has anything to do with map is

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

But that is certainly **not** your issue.

I think it is much more likely you have a greedy rewrite that is capturing that URL. Post the contents of your .htaccess and vhost config (if necessary).

Have a look at this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255474

Eg.

```
# ImapMenu can be none, formatted, semiformatted, unformatted
ImapMenu semiformatted
# ImapDefault can be error, nocontent, map, referer, or some useful URL.
#  The .map file overrides this.
ImapDefault map
# ImapBase can be map, referer, URL.  The .map file overrides this.
ImapBase referer
```

Comment: Imap is the problem. "Menu for" appears in the apache source in `./modules/mappers/mod_imagemap.c`

Comment: @MarkWagner, I think that's the answer I want - would you care to shift it to an answer as I can't accept a comment. As I understand it, your answer is substantially different to sonassi's.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular - no, he is stating my answer IS correct. `mod_imagemap.c` contains the directives I mentioned, look at the opening comments here - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache/apache-747.3/httpd/modules/mappers/mod_imagemap.c